# Sample Research Grant White Paper

Tags: research-process, funding, publications

I am working on a research grant proposal and the funding agency requires us to turn in a white paper before the actual proposal. I have no clue how a research grant white paper should look like. I tried googling and searching in the university library, but could not find anything similar. Will somebody be able to give me a link to a research grant white paper, something which I can look at and learn the format? (my field is computer science)

Comment: In what field?  For what funding agency?

Comment: What's a white paper?

Comment: Hi @JeffE, this is in computer science, and this is for a government funding.

Comment: @picmate: I haven't ever written a white paper myself, but I'm sure the required structure depends on the *specific* funding agency.  NSF?  DARPA?  DOE?  NIH?  DHS?  The main trick is to find someone who has written a successful white paper or proposal for _that_ agency (if not the specific program director).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on a little Googling, his white paper sounds like a preproposal. It is likely a short overview over your research project: the problem you are working on, your approach to solving it, how much it will cost, and what you and/or the agency will get out of it. Consider this white paper an outline of your full proposal.

Many agencies will ask for these if they expect a particular program or funding opportunity will have a high response or if the purpose of the program is to provide a single large award to one project. The prepreposals are used to narrow the field before they ask for full proposals from a smaller set of submitters.

I have not been successful at finding examples, since proposals and affiliated documents are almost never released unless they are funded. However, I have found some tips for preparing white papers from [Rochester Institute of Technology](http://www.rit.edu/research/srs/news/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=141&Itemid=114) and [Purdue](http://www.purdue.edu/research/vpr/funding/rdgn/rdgn2.pdf).

Comment: Well, the funded ones are the ones you'd want to see as examples.